# PowerShell - Upload Test and reduce the speed

Tags: powershell

It´s easy to find and or create a script to test the upload for a web based environment (For example SharePoint).

But how can I specify/reduce the upload speed?
I want to simulate big and slow uploads and wan´t to check if a upload reached a timeout from a infrastructure component.
I wan´t to copy this script to different locations in my infrastructure to check which component had the timeout problem.
(Changing the nework speed in the infrastructure is not a option)
The reason for this test is because a few users can only use slow internet connections (satellite, isdn, modem etc.) but had to upload big files.

How can I create a PowerShell script to upload a file with a very reduced speed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should look after NetAdapter at MSDN: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867(v=wps.630).aspx

For example

```
[cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [int]$ThrottleLimit = 5
        )

foreach -parallel -throttlelimit $ThrottleLimit ($n in 1..5){
   "Working on $n"
   "{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f (Get-Date)
   }

}
```

I hope you will find the right solution with my answer ;-)